# Save PyTorch dataset on disk: TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object

Tags: dataset, save, pickle, torch, disk

I am executing the code on https://github.com/notmahi/clip-fields/blob/main/demo/1%20-%20parse%20rgbd.ipynb

Once I create the "R3DSemanticDataset", I want to save the variable "dataset" with all the data. The problem is that when i try to save it on disk:

```
import torch
torch.save(dataset, '../nyu_views.pth')
```

The following error appears:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 3
      1 import torch
----> 3 torch.save(dataset, '../nyu_views.pth')

File ~/miniconda3/envs/cf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:379, in save(obj, f, pickle_module, pickle_protocol, _use_new_zipfile_serialization)
    377 if _use_new_zipfile_serialization:
    378     with _open_zipfile_writer(opened_file) as opened_zipfile:
--> 379         _save(obj, opened_zipfile, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)
    380         return
    381 _legacy_save(obj, opened_file, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/cf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:484, in _save(obj, zip_file, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)
    482 pickler = pickle_module.Pickler(data_buf, protocol=pickle_protocol)
    483 pickler.persistent_id = persistent_id
--> 484 pickler.dump(obj)
    485 data_value = data_buf.getvalue()
    486 zip_file.write_record('data.pkl', data_value, len(data_value))

TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, the problem was that I was saving to disk the dataset object, that was using a variable of outside the dataset:
[image]

I changed that, and made it be an input to the dataset, as path and custom classes are, and then i can save it to disk :D